# How do I get a delay between displaying images on Buttons?

Tags: java

I am trying to display dice but would like a delay between the displaying of each die.  My code follows.  What occurs with the code below is that the delay occurs but it occurs only once and then all the dice appear.  All the die are displayed at once after the delay. I would like the delay to occur for each iteration of the loop, displaying one die at a time after each delay.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBEROFDICE; i++)
            {
                try 
                {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                num = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                tempIcon = new StretchIcon("" + num + "die.png");
                addPicToButton(tempIcon, dice[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are doing this in the main Event loop, so the controls are not redrawn until you return from the method.  What you need to do is run this logic in a separate thread based on SwingWorker, where in that thread you would update the dice.